# Trying to change color of ActionBar homeAsUp button

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm unsuccessful trying to change the color of the `homeAsUp` button on the Android action bar. I need to do this at run time. Here is what I've got:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_register_one, menu);

    MenuItem homeItem = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        homeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.home);
    } else {
        homeItem = menu.findItem(R.id.up);
    }

    if (homeItem == null) {
        // I always wind up with a null homeItem
        Log.e(Constants.TAG, "null");
    } else {
        Drawable homeIcon = (Drawable) homeItem.getIcon();
        homeIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedVisualElements.primaryFontColorHexString()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        homeItem.setIcon(homeIcon);
    }

    // this part works just fine
    MenuItem nextItem = menu.findItem(R.id.next);
    Drawable newIcon = (Drawable)nextItem.getIcon();
    newIcon.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedVisualElements.primaryFontColorHexString()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    nextItem.setIcon(newIcon);

    return true;
}
```

This always winds up with the `homeItem` in a null state. My action bar looks like this (both arrows should be green and the same size):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `R.id.home` to `android.R.id.home`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this. Thanks to Parth Bhayani, but his solution used deprecated methods, and this doesn't:

```
Drawable upArrow = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back_white_48dp, null);

upArrow.mutate().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor(sharedVisualElements.primaryFon‌​tColorHexString()), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN); 

getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(upArrow);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it is better to not use the drawable `abc_ic_ab_back_mtrl_am_alpha` constants due to they can change in different OS versions, and in different support libraries. I use the following to get the drawable for the homeasup button:

```
{
    Drawable drawable;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        drawable = getSupportDrawableFromAttrIndex(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.ActionBar_homeAsUpIndicator);
    } else {
        drawable = getDrawableFromAttr(android.R.attr.homeAsUpIndicator);
    }
    // apply the tint color here before setting to the actionBar
    actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable);
}

Drawable getSupportDrawableFromAttrIndex(int index) {
    TypedArray ta = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(null,
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.ActionBar,
            android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.actionBarStyle,
            0);
    Drawable drawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(getActivity(), ta.getResourceId(index, 0));
    ta.recycle();
    return drawable;
}

protected Drawable getDrawableFromAttr(int attr) {
    int[] attrs = {attr};
    TypedArray ta = getActivity().obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.YOUR_APP_THEME, attrs);
    Drawable drawable = ta.getDrawable(0);
    ta.recycle();
    return drawable;
}
```

then you can apply the tint.